# Send a RTF file in the body of an email

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-4.0

My application generate reports as rtf-files. I want to send this file by 
email, but NOT as attachment, but inside the emailbody. And the receiver 
must see the formatted text. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could convert your RTF to HTML and then send it as HTML mail. Try with this :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27431/Writing-Your-Own-RTF-Converter

Answer (score 0):

Let's make some order here, email body is for standard TEXT only.

In order to send HTML just contsruct the email content from  tag as you would create an html page, most of email clients (especially web-based) will be able to show it as HTML to the reader as they follow the tags and format the page.

Regarding RTF - it is extremly non-standard and mostly supported in microsoft products that deals with emails, they will put some preheader in the body to mark it as RTF object.